# Laravel validate JSON

Tags: php, json, laravel, validation

I'm building a platform where users can create Orders using a REST API.

> I noticed when you 'malform' the JSON data it doesn't throw an error, it returns all validation errors, for example

```
{
    "supplier_id": 1,
    "firstname": "john",
    "lastname": "doe",
    "street": "janestreet",
    "number": 11,
    "city": "the city",
    "country": "BEL"", // <-- double closing quotes
}
```

This just returns all validation errors, as if nothing was passed.

```
  {
    "firstname": [
      "The firstname field is required."
    ],
    "lastname": [
      "The lastname field is required."
    ],
    "street": [
      "The street field is required."
    ],
    "number": [
      "The number field is required."
    ],
    "city": [
      "The city field is required."
    ],
    "country": [
      "The country field is required."
    ],
    "items": [
      "The items field is required."
    ]
  }
```

### I've tried

```
if(!$request->isJson()) {
    //return invalid response
}
```

Looking forward to your ideas!

Comment: I'd leave it as-is. The user posted malformed data, and as a result the API doesn't have any of those data fields it needs. It's up to the user to send valid JSON.

Comment: Can you show your validation rule

Answer (score 0):

You can add something like this to your `boot` method in `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`.

```
Validator::extend('valid_json', function ($attributes, $value, $parameters, $validation) {
    $json_string = $value;

    if(!is_string($json_string)) {
        return false;
    }
    json_decode($string);
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Try something like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make([
    'my_json' => $your_json_to_validate_from_post_or_file_etc,
], [
    'my_json' => 'required|valid_json'
];

if ($validator->fails()) {
    //
}
```

More generically, it can be used something like this in a custom `Request`:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'something' => 'required|valid_json',
    ];
}
```

or in a controller:

```
$validator = Validator::make($input_values, [
    'something' => 'required|valid_json',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    throw new Exception('JSON was invalid.');
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but this is a POST BODY json, not a posted attribute, see the post underneath here :)

Comment: I don't quire understand, where is the malformed json coming from exactly? I updated my answer, maybe it will be clearer to you now?

Comment: I do an API POST request to my Laravel app of the type application/json, but the json is malformed.

Comment: Can you post some more code? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @Notflip Why not just send well-formed JSON?